How can I find all unique sub graphs within a graph database such as memgraph?
I have a dataset of tens of thousands of directed subgraphs. The subgraphs are trees, they branch from the root node and never merge. I want to find all the unique subgraphs based on the event_type attribute of the nodes.
Currently I have a solution that returns all subgraphs, converts the subgraph into a NetworkX DiGraph, before calling the weisfeiler_lehman_graph_hash to return a unique hash for the graph. This isn't efficient nor does it make use of the graph database. Is there a way I can do this with Cypher queries or within the graph database itself?
